# Emulating test lists on a build agent using VS2013/TFS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, tfsbuild

How do you replace the 'old' test lists (as in a VS2008 vsmdi file) on a VS2013/TFS2013 build agent? We have VS2013 *Professional* and Team Foundation Server, and it seems that test lists are no longer supported, and the 'new' test playlists are not supported either for the TFS build agent. MSBUILD no longer seems to support the concept of lists.

Can someone clarify how you should execute selected lists of tests using MSBUILD on a TFS2013 build agent?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using MSBuild command, you need to choose to use [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.120).aspx) command. However, by default the **TfvcTemplate.12.xaml** build template does not support the **MSTest.exe** option when you select the **Test Runner** in the build definition. Good news is there is a simple way for you to make it work:

Instead of using TFS2013 build process template, you can choose to use TFS2012 build process template which enables MSTest. You can get it [here](https://code.openhub.net/file?fid=Yo8SCzBUmv2Ji5rAEqHbS-9je_g&cid=A_45bKBZeVo&s=&fp=412587&mp=&projSelected=true). Then select to use the TFS2012 build template, click to Automated Tests part, select **MSTest Test Metadata File** as test runner. 
[image]

Comment: Manually editing the 2013 template allows you to add the old MsTest activity back in, but consider it deprecated, the new test runner is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Test Filters. Tag your unit tests in source control using attributes:

```
[Category("ListX")]
[TestMethod]
public void Test(){ /* ... */ }
```

Then you can add a Test Filter to your build definition (sorry for the typo in the screenshot, should read `TestCategory=Critical`, or `ListX` in the example above:

[image]

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/xaml-build-staged-execution-of-unit-tests/

Comment: Thanks, but tagging 9000 test methods with an attribute is a big ask. We've resorted to running tests by assembly, and using categories just to exclude a small number. Whoever thought of the category attribute idea didn't think of the consequences for legacy code!

Comment: Indeed, I explain that filter approach in my blog post as well. I think Playlists were supposed to become more powerful and partially dynamic test lists, but that never saw the light.